# Syntaxerror : missing ) after argument

Tags: javascript, discord

So yeah I wanted to start my discord bot coded in js and then when I tried to do the last command node . This appeared

SyntaxError:missing) after argument

Any fix?  I got issue to post code so it's in comment

Code below added from OP's comment with some editing:

```
var discord = require("discord.js");
var client = Discord.client();
var prefix = '!';
var token = 'NzM1NjI4OTEzMzY3MDU2NDA0.XxnRyQ.X2H-FP1DSRq97DoyRtYnEpqmI5s';
client.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("ready");
};
client.on("message", message => { });
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax error

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a ) somewhere. Without seeing the code we can't help you. We are not mind readers.

Comment: const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = Discord.client();

var prefix = '!'
var token = 'NzM1NjI4OTEzMzY3MDU2NDA0.XxnRyQ.X2H-FP1DSRq97DoyRtYnEpqmI5s'

client.on("ready", function() {
 console.log("ready")
}

client.on("message", message => {
 
})

client.login(token);

Comment: @hibot it'd be helpful for you to edit your original question with syntax highlighting. Please also add the tag `discord`

Answer (score 0):

In the code I added to your question - from your comment, "ready" is missing a `)`:

```
var discord = require("discord.js");
var client = Discord.client();
var prefix = '!';
var token = 'NzM1NjI4OTEzMzY3MDU2NDA0.XxnRyQ.X2H-FP1DSRq97DoyRtYnEpqmI5s';
client.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("ready");
)}; // <- missing ")" here
client.on("message", message => { });
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Uhhh now it's unexpected token ')'

Comment: where?  click on the error - it will, at least, show you which line...